# In R , how to summarize data frame in multiple dimensions

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

There is dataframe `raw_data` as below, How can i change it to `wished_data` in easy way ?

I currently know `group_by/summarise` the data serval times (and add variables) , then `rbind` them. But this is little boring , especially when  variables  more then this example in occasion.

I want to know ,if is there any general method for similar situation ? Thanks!

```
library(tidyverse)
country <- c('UK','US','UK','US')
category <- c("A", "B", "A", "B")
y2021 <- c(17, 42, 21, 12)
y2022 <- c(49, 23, 52, 90)
```

raw_data <- data.frame(country,category,y2021,y2022)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

We may use `rollup/cube/groupingsets` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
out <- rbind(setDT(raw_data), groupingsets(raw_data, j = lapply(.SD, sum), 
  by = c("country", "category"), 
    sets = list("country", "category", character())))
out[is.na(out)] <- 'TOTAL'
```

-output

```
> out
   country category y2021 y2022
    <char>   <char> <num> <num>
1:      UK        A    17    49
2:      US        B    42    23
3:      UK        A    21    52
4:      US        B    12    90
5:      UK    TOTAL    38   101
6:      US    TOTAL    54   113
7:   TOTAL        A    38   101
8:   TOTAL        B    54   113
9:   TOTAL    TOTAL    92   214
```

---

Or with `cube`

```
out <- rbind(raw_data, cube(raw_data, 
  j = .(y2021= sum(y2021), y2022=sum(y2022)), by = c("country", "category")))
out[is.na(out)] <- 'TOTAL'
```

Comment: For code 1 , rows 5:6  will not what i want, even ther result just the same ( it's group by country+category, i only want to group by category).  The code 2 working well, it's greate ! Thanks!

Comment: Right, if  add another country in raw data , code 1 will not retrun what I want. Thanks!

Comment: @anderwyang i removed the first option.  Hope you don't have an issue with removing that option?

Comment: Just use function cube to replace rollup, your code1 will be no problem. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 2):

We can use the adorn_totals function from janitor.  get_totals accepts a data frame and a column and it outputs the data frame with totals for  the numeric columns, one such row for each level of the specified column.  It then extracts out the total rows and since adorn_totals can rearrange the column order uses select to put the order back to the original so that we can later bind mulitiple instances together.  We then bind together the orignal data frame and each of the total row data frames that we want.

```
library(dplyr)
library(janitor)

get_totals <- function(data, col) {
  data %>%
    group_by({{col}}) %>%
    group_modify(~ adorn_totals(.)) %>%
    ungroup %>%
    filter(rowSums(. == "Total") > 0) %>%
    select(any_of(names(data)))
}

bind_rows(
  raw_data,
  get_totals(raw_data, category), 
  get_totals(raw_data, country), 
  get_totals(raw_data)
)
```

giving:

```
  country category y2021 y2022
1      UK        A    17    49
2      US        B    42    23
3      UK        A    21    52
4      US        B    12    90
5   Total        A    38   101
6   Total        B    54   113
7      UK    Total    38   101
8      US    Total    54   113
9   Total        -    92   214
```